# How to throw an error inside a private method inside a service with Mockito

Tags: java, spring, testing, mockito

I have an issue trying to make some automated tests : I have a service (spring). This service is providing a public method, used for a process. This process is made of 3 underlaying processes. Those processes are in private methods, and are calling some other services.

I want to test the behavior when one of those 3 private process is throwing an error. I figured out that Mockito could help me. However I can't make it work. As my three methods are private and I can't use PowerMock, I tried using when().thenThrow on the public methods in the other service, which is called by my private method.

I got various results, NullPointerException, process working without any throw/error, dependencies issues etc.

My code looks like :

```
 @Test
public void test() throws Throwable {
    Mockito.when(SecondServiceCalledByPrivateMethod.publicMethod(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any()))
            .thenThrow(new Exception("failed!!!"));
    request lRequest = createRequest(myObjects);

    FirstService.executeProcess(lRequest);
}
```

With a config class :

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigClass{

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public SecondService secondService() {
        return Mockito.mock(SecondService.class);
    }

}
```

Inside services, I have multiple @Autowired etc. I don't know if it matters. It's the first time I try to use Mockito.
Do you have any idea how to make it works or what I am missing ?

EDIT : my service looks like :

```
@Service
class MyService {
    @Autowired OtherService dependentService;

    public someObject serviceMethod(Object2) {
        //Some actions
        callProcess(Object2);
    }
    private void callProcess(Object2) {
        // other actions
        dependentService.process(Object3);
    }
}
```

It has multiple calls to other services (@Autowired). Do I need to Mock / spy them in the test ?

Comment: Please provide some sample to work it out. Did you try this option  Mockito.doThrow(new Exception()).when(instance).methodName(); ?

Comment: I did try it, but then read about the fact that it needs the method to b a void one. Mine has a return object.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really make the service's private method itself throw an Exception.

The general concept to use for this kind of thing is to mock the dependencies.

```
@Service
class MyService {
    @Autowired OtherService dependentService;

    public void serviceMethod() {
        callProcess();
    }
    private void callProcess() {
        dependentService.process();
    }
}

@RunWith(MockitoRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTest {
    // will be injected into the tested service by mockito
    @Mock private OtherService dependentService;
    @InjectMocks private MyService tested;

    @Test
    public void testExceptionOnCallProcess() {
        // mock the exception being thrown by the other service
        when(dependentService.process()).thenThrow(new RuntimeException());
        tested.serviceMethod();
    }
}
```

What you are doing with your own configuration is creating an actual Spring context - that would make it an integration test, and since you don't have mocks in those, you can't create a mock exception. You'll have to trigger one by creating the circumstances that will throw one by setting up the environment and data accordingly.

Comment: I tried this solution but I got a bunch of nullPointerException when using it.
I don't know if it's important to mention, but there is a facade before the service itself (I do open a new spring transaction inside the facade).
I also tried callng the service without the facade, but got another npe.